# Create statistics by features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, spatialite, spatial-statistics

I've a polygon layer for parcels in a landscape protection area and a point layer, contains zoological data (e.g species, entities, etc.).

How can I make a statics for each polygon, contains the list of observed species, the count of observations by species and the sum of entities by species?

I would like to make it in QGIS with shapefiles or spatialite database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a spatial database like spatialite this is a straightforward query. Suppose you have the polygons as `parcels` and the point layer is `zoological` (and both are spatial tables in spatialite). I'll assume the parcels has a unique id called `parcel_id` and the species has `species_id` as well as `species_name` and `entity`. The query would be something like:

```
SELECT p.parcel_id, z.species_name, Count(z.species_id), Sum(z.entity)
FROM parcels AS p JOIN zoological AS z
ON ST_Contains(p.geometry, z.geometry) 
GROUP BY p.parcel_id, z.species_id
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I wanted. The other method, mentioned by underdark is similar, but not the same. I tried that, but didn't work.